# I have a question about a multi-threaded data transfer program

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm learning about Multithread.

**Single thread code - Server**

```
#include "common.h" // Header file that contains a collection of headers used by default
#include <Windows.h>
#define SERVERPORT 9000
#define BUFSIZE    256

int main()
{
    int retval;


    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
        return 1;

    SOCKET listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) err_quit("socket()");


    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    retval = bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) err_quit("bind()");

    retval = listen(listen_sock, SOMAXCONN);
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) err_quit("listen()");

    SOCKET client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    int addrlen;
    char buf[BUFSIZE]{};
    int namelen;
    char filename[128]{};


    while (1) {
        addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        client_sock = accept(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &addrlen);
        if (client_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            err_display("accept()");
            break;
        }


        char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientaddr.sin_addr, addr, sizeof(addr));
        printf("\n[TCP] Client Access: IP Address=%s, Port Number=%d\n",
            addr, ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port));



        retval = recv(client_sock, (char*)&namelen, sizeof(int), MSG_WAITALL);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv()");
            break;
        }
        printf("File Length:%d\n", namelen);

        retval = recv(client_sock, filename, namelen, MSG_WAITALL);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv()");
            break;
        }

        printf("\nFile Name: %s\n", filename);


        int bytes, allLen = 0;
        float curLen = 0;

        retval = recv(client_sock, (char*)&allLen, sizeof(int), MSG_WAITALL);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv()");
            break;
        }


        FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

        while (1)
        {

            retval = recv(client_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_WAITALL);
            if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                err_display("recv()");
                break;
            }
            curLen += fwrite(buf, 1, retval, fp);
            memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            printf("percent : %2.2f%%\r", (float)curLen / (float)allLen * 100.0f);
            if (curLen == allLen)
            {
                printf("\nFinished\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    closesocket(listen_sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

**Multi thread code - Server**

```
#include "common.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#define SERVERPORT 9000
#define BUFSIZE    256

int clients{};
HANDLE hEvent;

DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID arg)
{
    int retval;
    SOCKET client_sock = (SOCKET)arg;
    char buf[BUFSIZE]{};
    int namelen{};
    char filename[128]{};

    while (1)
    {
        if (clients > 1)
            retval = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);

        retval = recv(client_sock, (char*)&namelen, sizeof(int), MSG_WAITALL);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv()");
            break;
        }
        printf("File Length:%d\n", namelen);

        retval = recv(client_sock, filename, namelen, MSG_WAITALL);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv()");
            break;
        }

        printf("\nFile Name: %s\n", filename);


        int allLen = 0;
        float curLen = 0;

        retval = recv(client_sock, (char*)&allLen, sizeof(int), MSG_WAITALL);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv()");
            break;
        }

        printf("File Size: %d\n", allLen);


        FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
        threads++;
        
        while (1)
        {
            retval = recv(client_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_WAITALL);
            if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                err_display("recv()");
                break;
            }
            else if (retval == 0)
                break;

            curLen += fwrite(buf, 1, retval, fp);
            memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            printf("Percent : %2.2f%%\r", (float)curLen / (float)allLen * 100.0f);
            if (curLen == allLen)
            {
                printf("\nFinished\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        break;
    }
    closesocket(client_sock);
    clients--;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int retval;


    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
        return 1;

    SOCKET listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) err_quit("socket()");


    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    retval = bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) err_quit("bind()");

    retval = listen(listen_sock, SOMAXCONN);
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) err_quit("listen()");

    SOCKET client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    int addrlen;

    HANDLE hThread;

    while (1) {
        addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        client_sock = accept(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &addrlen);
        if (client_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            err_display("accept()");
            break;
        }

        clients++;
        char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientaddr.sin_addr, addr, sizeof(addr));
        printf("\n[TCP] Client Access: IP Address=%s, Port Number=%d\n",
            addr, ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port));

        hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThread, (LPVOID)client_sock, 0, NULL);
        if (hThread == NULL) { closesocket(client_sock); }
        else { CloseHandle(hThread); }



    }
    closesocket(listen_sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

**Send Code in Client Program**

```
while (1)
    {
        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        printf("Input file name to send:");
        scanf("%s", buf);

        FILE* fp = fopen(buf, "rb");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Wrong Input\n");
            return 0;
        }


        len = (int)strlen(buf);


        retval = send(sock, (char*)&len, sizeof(int), 0);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("send()");
            return 0;
        }


        retval = send(sock, buf, len, 0);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("send()");
            return 0;
        }


        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        AllLen = ftell(fp);


        retval = send(sock, (char*)&AllLen, sizeof(int), 0);
        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("send()");
            return 0;
        }

        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        int SendPercent = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            len = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, fp);
            if (len)
            {

                retval = send(sock, buf, len, 0);
                if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    err_display("send()");
                    return 0;
                }

                SendPercent += len;
                printf("percent : %2.2f%%\r", (float)SendPercent / (float)AllLen * 100.0f);
                memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            }
            else if (SendPercent == AllLen)
            {
                printf("\nFinished\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Single thread code works fine, but using multi-threaded code causes problems that I cannot understand.
There was no problem with the compilation, but the percentages shown in the two programs were different and the files received were not in normal condition.
What is the cause of the problem?
How can I analyze the cause?
It's a complicated and strange question, but it's hard for me to even figure out the cause of the problem. Please help me.

Comment: I recommend to simplify down the code.  I would change the client code to just be a fixed set of sends (don't bother reading real file content, etc).  Similarly, on the server side, narrow it down.  Then you can add back in bit by bit until something goes wrong.  Another thing you can try - use `strace` on the server exectuable to verify what is being received.

Comment: `clients--` : data race.  You cannot use a normal variable to communicate between threads.  At the very least it has to be `_Atomic`.  May or may not be the cause of your problem, but it's certainly *a* bug.